# Types of input signal of a BJT

Tags: transistors, analog, bjt

What kind of signal do we have to at the base of a transistor? Is it a current signal or voltage signal? On the other side, what kind of output (amplified) signal do we expect? Is it a current or voltage signal?

They said the output current is current gain times base current, so it seems that they are using current as base signal, but then why do they add a voltage source (AC) to give signal?

Comment: You can't separate voltage from current. BJT by its nature is a current amplifier (in a sense that you have a defined ratio between the input and output currents). But in practice you often want a voltage amplifier. So you build a voltage amplifier which is utilizing BJT's current amplification properties.

Comment: A voltage source can deliver current into a resistor. Just as a current source can deliver voltage to a resistor.

Comment: it means if we give a sine wave (VOLTAGE)  is it fair to expect magnified version of this sine As OUTPUT CURRENT?

Comment: Take a simple single-transistor amplifier circuit ang go through the calculations. It will be the most explanatory, really.

Answer (score 4):

(assuming small signals)

If you have a current source, you supply a current, and the base voltage will assume whatever voltage is needed to accept that current.

If you have a voltage source, you apply a voltage, and the transistor characteristics and the emitter impedance work together to form an "input impedance" which allows a certain base current depending on the input voltage.

At the output side, you get a current according to beta (from input current, A/A) or transconductance (gm, from the input voltage, A/V).

Then the load resistances on the collector (Rc) determine the voltage Vc according to that current Ic.

Vc = Supply - Ic * Rc.

There is no difference between output current = input current * beta, or output current = input voltage * transconductance : they are just front view and side view of the same face.

(Large signal, e.g. if the voltages exceed the supply rails, get messy. Ignore them until you have a handle on small signal behaviour)

Comment: good explanation, but i want to ask one question precisely if we use a current signal , then the output current is going to the same amplified version (assuming in the active region)of the of the original copy, but thee question is if i apply a voltage signal at the base are we gonna get the same voltage wave form at the out put like currrent?

Comment: 1) note that beta is not a constant but (in the linear region) weakly dependent on Vce ... see any transistor datasheet. So even current in, current out isn't perfectly linear. 2) Consider how current varies with forward voltage in a forward biased diode ... with voltage input, you're dealing with the same thing in a transistor, so current output is much less linear. You want to keep the Vbe variation to a minimum ... and the art of designing transistor amplifiers starts there. The first step is to add an emitter resistor. Lower gain, but better linearity.

Answer (score 3):

A bipolar transistor is essentially a current amplifier. Voltages are applied only in order to create and control those currents. In particular, the output current is more than that supplied by the input signal, so it has to be driven in from somewhere else.

In practice the input and/or output current is often passed through a resistor, in order to convert the signal from/to a voltage.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a verification of the claim ("current amplifier") - other than the relation Ic=B*Ib (which is a correlation only). Instead, both currents Ic and Ib (like Ie) are exponentially related to the voltage Vbe. This can be verified !!

Comment: @LvW Would "Bipolar transistors work as current-controlled current regulators" do you? See https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/bipolar-junction-transistors-bjt/ This was the first page returned in a web search on "how does a bipolar transistor work?"; I can't be ***ed to look further down the list, you might like to.

Comment: @Guy_Inchbald...I do not blindly trust internet contributions. Instead, I rely on serious books and my own brain. Question: Do you have  or did you find any verification (proof) of the claim "current-controlled" in the linked document? Do you need proofs for voltage-control? No problem!

Comment: @LvW >Sigh< Fine, be like that. I threw my degree textbooks out when I left the fab industry, sorry I can't help you there. Just one tip for you not to believe either; voltage output control requires a series resistor (or equivalent) for the current to develop the voltage across, and is therefore a circuit application and not an intrinsic function of the device itself.

Comment: I must admit that I do not understand the meaning of your answer ("voltage output control"?). And I do not know which resistor you suddenly brings into the game...The basic question is if Shockleys exponential equation Ic=f(Vbe) is the one which determines the output current or is it Ic=B*Ib (which to me is a simple correlation).

Answer (score -2):

Question: "*The fundamental question I would like to ask is that what kind of signal we give at the base of a transistor ? Is it a current signal or voltage signal?*"

- When you are asking what kind of signal (voltage or current) "we give at the base" - the answer is: As you like. We can do both.
- However, if you want to know how a transistor (physically) really works  - that means: Does the output current Ic react upon a change of input current Ib or input voltage Vbe (betweenn B and E) ? In this case, the answer is: The bipolar transistor is a voltage driven device.
- Please note that this statement can be prooved based on theoretical as well as practical considerations. Several observations supprt this view. But you should note that - for some calculations during design and analysis of transistor stages - you can, of course, use the relation Ic=(B*Ib) because there always will be a base current Ib. But the relation Ic=(B * Ib) is a correlation only and does not reflect a cause-and-result effect.

Comment: Thinking of the BJT as a voltage-controlled device is technically true and practically not very useful. When actually using bipolar transistors, in almost every situation, it's easier to think of them as current-controlled.

Comment: @Hearth...please, answer my questions: Using the current-controlled view, can you explain (a) the principle of Re-feedback, (b) the background of the temp-co -2mV/K, (c) the working principle of a cascode stage, (d) the function of a simple current mirror, (e) the fact that the voltage gain is independent on h21 (same bias point), (f)  the cross-over distortions in class-B.operation, (g) the Early effect,...?? Can you? Therefore, give me ONE SINGLE example where the current-control view simplifies design and analysis.

Comment: It is surprising that a correct answer - which is in accordance with theory and practice (and with the worlds best known electronics engineers) - gets a downvote in this forum. Not a good sign.

Comment: It gets a downvote because it's not a useful thing to tell a beginner. I'm not the one who downvoted, but I can see why. None of the things you mentioned here are relevant to a beginner who is probably using the transistor as a current amplifier for a microcontroller or as a common-emitter amplifier, both of which are applications made simpler by the current-controlled view.

Comment: Well - the questioner was asking if it is a current or a voltage which is applied to the input. I have answered this at the beginning of my contribution. However, according to my experience (with students) I have learned, that it is very important to be able to discriminate between (a) physical laws and (b) practical assunptions. That was the main content of my answer. By the way: Why did you not give me one example where your view (according to your own words) in "almost every situation" would be "easier"? I am curious...

Comment: @Hearth-as I can read, you agree that my view is "technically true". Fine. But if I understand you correctly, at the same time you prefer to give the questioner an answer which would be not "technicaly true". Why? I always prefer to tell the (physical) truth - and, if necessary, to mention at the same time simplifying views - and their limitations!! Thats what I did.

Comment: I did give you two cases where it's easier: amplifying the current from a microcontroller, and using it as a common-emitter amplifier (essentially the same case, though.); these are in my experience the most common uses for a BJT.

Comment: With all respect - did you ever design or analyze a common-emitter stage? It is really not a "good" example for supporting your view. And dont forget: The voltage gain formula contains the transconductance gm !. As an example - here is my sequence: Select Vcc, select Ic, define Rc and Re, calculate Ve, apply Vbe=0,65...07 V, find Vb, select and calculate the  bias divider,...now at the end you can take Ib into account when choosing a divider current of I>10Ib. In many cases, you even can neglect Ib. Thats all!. At which point did you use current-control? Instead, you have used a voltage Vbe

Comment: To make it clear: I am interested to see an example, where I must use the current-control approach for designing/analyzing a circuit. Up to now - I have not seen such an example. On the other hand - I have mentioned some examples which show that some observations can only (!) be explained with voltage-control.

Comment: I must admit - it is interesting (and really disappointing) that there is no answer to my question, but instead a downvoting. But this is not a new experience for me. The question "voltage vs. current control" seems to be a religious one.

Comment: Again, I did not downvote your answer. Nothing you have said here is wrong, I just think it's not helpful. The current-driven view is easier to work with when you just need something to work, particularly because the collector current is approximately linear with base current, while the voltage controlled formula is nonlinear. It's clear that anything I say is going to be met with the same argument again though, so I'm just not going to say anything more here.